# How can I set a value in my viewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following:

```
namespace Test {

public class Location {
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class BaseViewModel {
    public BaseViewModel() {
        Location = new Location { city = "Paris"; };
    }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class EditViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    Location = "France";
}

}
```

This seem like a strange requirement but how can I set the value of Location from within the EditViewModel? The line below gives the following error:

```
Location = "France";
Error   2   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor.

```
public EditViewModel ()  {
  Location = "France";
}
```

or better add a specialized constructor and a default constructor:

```
    public EditViewModel (string LocationText)  {
      Location = LocationText;
    }

    public EditViewModel() : this("France") { }
```

just to be precise, don't use string, use your Object, I've used string for quickening.

Comment: I think it is better to not use a specialized constructor. Matter of opinion, but when you do that, you may find yourself constantly changing constructors every time you want to initialize another property. The only time I do that is when I have no default constructor and I need to force some fields to be initialized.

Comment: @RobKent I may agree if the hierarchy tree is deep, but with just two classes I guess he should have no problem at all. I prefer to use extensively  the : base() or : this() thing (Is it called initialization list also in C# ?), but as you perfectly stated, it just depends on personal tastes and scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You need to istantiate the object Location, not to set it as a string:

```
Location = new Location { city = "France" };
```

and it's better if you rename the property with a different name, do not use the class name.

```
public class BaseViewModel { 
    public BaseViewModel() { 
        CurrentLocation = new Location { city = "Paris"; }; 
    } 
    public Location CurrentLocation { get; set; } 
}

public class EditViewModel : BaseViewModel { 
    public Book Book { get; set; } 
    public EditViewModel() : base()
    {
        CurrentLocation = new Location { city = "France"; }; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you just need to change EditViewModel class..**

Like this:

```
public class EditViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public EditViewModel(){
        Location = "France";
    }
}
```

*You were trying to set value to the base class property in class's scope.. **which is not allowed..**

**You can do this in constructor on any other method within a class.. As I mentioned above..**

Hope this help !